# Destroying optical discs (that aren't re-writable) with a CD burner

Tags: security, compact-disc, optical-drive

Is it possible to use a CD burner to destroy data on a disc? I believe this would be possible with a re-writable disc, but would there be a way to 'force' the drive to write random data with the laser over a one-time-burn disc? Would this even do anything?

Comment: Not that I'm trying to help, but breaking the disc shouldn't be enough? Only like the government or so will be able AND somehow will want to read that data... the disc would be not writable anyways.

Comment: Or microwaving it apparently !!!

Comment: I'm asking it out of curiosity

Comment: Really wonder how this would stand up against forensics. Suppose worse than magnetic media as the CDs contain lots of error correction bits.

Comment: mind you, it'd supplement physically destroying the disc quite well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few burners support overwriting by using very strong laser power.  Look here for Liteon's explanation of "[Smarterase](http://www.liteonit.eu/en/smarterase/smarterase.html)".  Most writers don't support this though.